# How to Save Partial Video to Gallery in Flutter Using Dio and Image Gallery Saver?

Tags: ios, flutter, amazon-s3, video, permissions

I am attempting to download a partial video from AWS S3 using Dio's download function, and I am saving it to the documents directory with `path_provider` in my Flutter app. The code I'm using works perfectly when downloading a complete video (API status code 200), but I encounter an issue when trying to download a partial video (API status code 206).

Here's the relevant code:

```
File? file = Dio().download(
  videoUrl,
  getApplicationDocumentsDirectoryPath(),
  options: startByte != null && endByte != null
      ? Options(
          headers: {
            'Range': 'bytes=$startByte-$endByte',
          },
        )
      : null,
);

if (file != null) {
  saveVideo(file.path);
}

Future<bool> saveVideo(String videoPath) async {
  final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveFile(
    videoPath,
    isReturnPathOfIOS: Platform.isIOS,
  );
  return result != null && result['isSuccess'];
}
```

The saveVideo function uses `image_gallery_saver` to save the video to the gallery. It works for complete videos but returns false with the error message `Failed to save, please check whether the permission is enabled` when trying to save a partial video.

Please note that I am running this on iOS and have not tested it on any other platform yet. Can anyone help me figure out how to save partial videos to the gallery successfully?